# Laravel 5.1: .htaccess redirect trailing slash gives googlebot redirect error

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.1, google-search-console

In my Laravel 5.1 project inside .htaccess with the default shipping I got:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above is giving me a problem because when I try to fetch as google in webmaster tools, I get a redirect error because the default url is http://domain.com/blog, and google is trying to fetch http://domain.com/blog/ and when it hits /blog/ instead of /blog, it redirects back to /blog because of the .htaccess lines above.

The question: would removing this cause any problems? Because then the site can be accessed from both trailing and not trailing slashs.

If so, can someone recommend me a better approach to not having this redirect error with google or other search engines?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual error message?